# E1696 cannot open source file "stdafx.h" during compilation

Tags: c++, header, visual-studio-2019, precompiled-headers, stdafx.h

I have two projects A and B. In project A, I have created a source file called Logger.cpp where I have #include "stdafx.h" in the includes part. The stdafx.h is present in the project A. In project A's properties, I have project B's header file locations in the 'Additional include directories' property.
When I am trying to compile the solution in **Visual Studio 2013**, it gets compiled successfully, but when I try to migrate my solution to **Visual Studio 2019** and compile the whole solution, or only project A, I am getting the error **E1696    cannot open source file "stdafx.h"** .

What I have tried:

1. I have copied the stdafx.h file from project A to project B which results in conflicts and does not allow me to open any header file included in the stdafx.h file.
2. I have deleted project A completely and then created a new C++ project as stdafx.h file gets created when a new project gets created.

Both the above approach does not resolve the issue.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files?view=msvc-160), when you create a new project in Visual Studio, a precompiled header file named pch.h is added to the project. (In Visual Studio 2017 and earlier, the file was called stdafx.h.)

So, you could set `stdafx.h` in `Properties->C/C++->Precompiled Header->Precompiled Header file`.

[image]